# PHP Parse % left characters of a string

Tags: php

I need to match some strings on 80% of the left characters. I can use `len()` and then figure out what 80% of that length is and set that as variable. Then I can do `substr($var, 0, $len80)`

That should select 80% of the string but being that I am in 2 loops and I have to do it on both sides I was hoping for a better way of doing this. Anyone know of a easier and more efficient way of selecting a certain percent of a string?

**UPDATE**

I ended up doing it like this `$a2 = substr($a, 0, (strlen($a) * .80));`

Same concept just did not have to set multiple variables.

Comment: what do you mean by `am in 2 loops and I have to do it on both sides` can you add some of your code ?

Comment: I think that you are mistaken that you have a problem in this matter. The code will run quite fast, and any other function will inevitably take more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grabbing the left 80% is pretty trivial:

```
$string = "This is my string";
$length = strlen($string);

echo substr($string, 0, $length * .8);
```

To grab 50% from the middle, offset by 25% on the starting position:

```
$result = substr($string, $length * .25, $length * .5);

// Outputs '...is my s...'
echo "..." . trim($result) . "...";
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/EZnoo2SZ

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used a variation of this.